# how set object date type to number in typescript

Tags: typescript

I need to convert the specified field in the object from date type to timestamp

**Expected function**

```js
let formData = {
   username: "tom",
   startDate: new Date(),
   endtDate: new Date(),
   ...
}

formData = objectDateToStamp(formData, ["startDate", "endDate"]);

// formData
// { username: "tome", startDate: 1629874054212,  endDate: 1629874054212};
```

** Current function **

```js
function objectDateToStamp<
   T extends Record<string, unknown>,
   U extends Array<keyof T>,
>(target: T, keys: U) {
   const obj = { ...target };

   (Object.keys(target) as Array<keyof T>).forEach((key) => {
      const value = obj[key];

      if (keys.includes(key) && value instanceof Date) {
         obj[key] = value.getTime();
         // Type 'number' cannot be assigned to type't [keyof t] '
         // alternative：value.getTime() as any 
      }
   });

   return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is occurring because the type of a variable cannot change in TypeScript. `obj` is the same type as `T`, so you cannot change the type of a property to from `Date` to `number`.

While you could silence the error by doing `value.getTime() as typeof obj[typeof key]`, the inferred return type is still `T`, which is incorrect.

I would write the function like this (using the `KeysMatching`):

```ts
type KeysMatching<T, V> = {[K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never}[keyof T];

function objectDateToStamp<
  T extends Record<string, unknown>,
  U extends KeysMatching<T, Date>
>(target: T, keys: readonly U[]): Omit<T, U> & Record<U, number> {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(target).map(([key, value]) => [
      key,
      (keys as readonly string[]).includes(key)
        ? (value as Date).getTime()
        : value,
    ])
  ) as Omit<T, U> & Record<U, number>;
}

let formData = {
  username: "tom",
  startDate: new Date(),
  endDate: new Date(),
};

// { username: string; startDate: number; endDate: number }
objectDateToStamp(formData, ["startDate", "endDate"]);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#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)